# 400 Bad Request call when I try to send data through Ajax after pagination

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django

I am pretty new to coding, so I apologize if this is not clear.  I have created a quiz app with Django that takes yes or no answers for any question, and when ever a no answer is given, a Modal should pop up asking for the user to provide more details. This modal passes the information back to the database with an ajax call when the user hits submit. Everything works fine on the first question, but after the second question loads in the pagination, I get a 400 (bad request) error, and the console shows that all of my hidden fields with initial conditions are blank. I had previously resolved this by having the page refresh after each submission, but that does not save my answer to the database, only allows me to pass the modal information.  Here is the code for my ajax

```
        $(document).ready(function(){           
    $("#submit-btn").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $("#question-form").serializeArray();
        var indexed_array = {};

        $.map(formData, function(n, i){
            indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
        });
        var answer = indexed_array.answer_id;
        console.log(answer);
        if (answer != 2) {
            $("#question-form").submit()
        }           
        else {
            $("#questionModal").modal("show");    

           }
        $("#sendDiscrepancyForm").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault()    
            var mForm = $("#sendForm").serialize()
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'ajax_hit_list'  %}",
                data: mForm,              
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                    $("#modalMessage").html("<p>This was Successful</p>")

                       $("#questionModal").modal("hide")
                        $("#question-form").submit()
                            location.reload()
                },
                error: function(data){ 
                    var obj = data.responseJSON
                    console.log(obj)
                    $("#modalMessage").html("<p>Please Fill out All Fields!</p>");
                }
            });

        });
    });        
});
```

and here is the code for my modal

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="questionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Discrepancy</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {% if queryset.has_next %}
        <form id ='sendForm' method='POST' action='{% url "ajax_hit_list" %}'>{% csrf_token %}
        {% else %}
        <form id ='sendForm' method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
        {% endif %}
        <span>

           {{ hitform.user.as_hidden }}
            {{ hitform.ships.as_hidden }}
            {{ hitform.ships.as_hidden }}
            {{ hitform.system.as_hidden }}
            {{ hitform.discover_date.as_hidden }}
            <h4>Department: {{ hitform.department }}</h4>
            <p id='modalMessage'></p>
            <h4>Description: {{ hitform.description }}</h4>
            <h4>Repair Schedule: {{ hitform.repair_schedule }}</h4>
            <h4>SAT: {{ hitform.sat }}</h4>
            <h4>STO: {{ hitform.sto }}</h4>
            <h4>JSN: {{ hitform.jsn }}</h4>         
        </span>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendDiscrepancyForm">
      </form>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the view I try to pass the data from the modal to

```
def discrepancy_modal(request, **kwargs):
hitform = DiscrepancyForm(request.POST or None)
today = date.today()
if request.method == "POST":
    if hitform.is_valid():
        ships = hitform.cleaned_data['ships']
        system = hitform.cleaned_data['system']
        description = hitform.cleaned_data['description']           
        department = hitform.cleaned_data['department']
        repair_schedule = hitform.cleaned_data['repair_schedule']
        sat = hitform.cleaned_data['sat']
        sto = hitform.cleaned_data['sto']
        jsn = hitform.cleaned_data['jsn']

        new_discrepancy = Discrepancy()
        new_discrepancy.user = request.user
        new_discrepancy.ships = ships
        new_discrepancy.system = system
        new_discrepancy.department = department

        new_discrepancy.description = description
        new_discrepancy.discover_date = today
        new_discrepancy.repair_schedule = repair_schedule
        new_discrepancy.sat = sat
        new_discrepancy.sto = sto
        new_discrepancy.jsn = jsn
        new_discrepancy.save()
        return HttpResponse('Success')
    if hitform.errors:
        print hitform.errors
        json_data = json.dumps(hitform.errors)
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(json_data, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
context = {
    "hitform": hitform,
}
return render(request, "form.html", context)
```